# Implementation of Login and Registration with help of VueJs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I would like to build an admin panel in vue js from scratch. I have install AdminLte theme via npm and copy the contents of header,sidebar and footer in components.My server side technology is Laravel.

Now I would like to build login and registration features in Vuejs so that only DB communication depends on laravel but I am confused and not sure about how to approach this?

Anyone can me with any ideas?

Comment: If u do need a SPA application, then read about oauth2. Laravel got official package called Laravel Passport for this purposes.

Comment: @GONG thanks for your response and guidance.

Comment: You should add more info on how you want to application / website to behave in order to gve a meaningful answer. If you want to use blade views it will be totally different from a single page application using the vue router. Is it only about sending the requests? Is it the general flow?

Comment: @Frank Provost I am talking about the general flow as I will be using Vue router and trying to build SPA. The request will be handled by laravel. So to approach this scenario?

Comment: I can only give high level advice as I don't know a lot about your use-case. A general appraoch is to have an interceptor in your frontend http client (axios usually for vue). Whenever a request returns a 401 (unauthorized) you send them to your login page. Your login page does a post to the login endpoint which returns 200 for ok or 400 / 422 for errors (example). on 200 you send them to your initial entry. This will work when using the web middleware. Since you typically load data that requires authentication on your "dashboard" it should always send users to the login page if not logged in.